# Reputation in project

Tags: postdocs

I would like to know your opinion about the following situation. I am currently a postdoc working on a project that is a continuation of my PhD work. The results are very promising and it seems likely that there will be a follow up project of the work while funding would be given by a prestigious grant.

However, since I did not work in academia for a few years and joined academia again for this project out of curiosity I am not the project leader. Due to this grant the project leader would get a tenure position in the end. I feel a bit fooled, because I did essentially all the work and I even wrote parts of the proposal for the follow-up project because the project leader is not really knowledgeable about the subject of the project.

I have the promise from the leader of the group that something similar is planned for me in the future but this is really uncertain because no one knows if such an opportunity will come again. I knew, that if the project will work out, that the current project leader would get the reputation, but now this does not seem right to me.
I will still be working in the follow-up project and without me it would not go on, but my motivation is going to zero at the moment.

What do you think about this situation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "What do you think about this situation?" is quite vague and opinion-based, what exactly is your question?

Comment: In what way were you fooled? You left, the project continued (for a few years!), you rejoin and want, well, what exactly? Jealously never works out particularly well.

Comment: @Jon. That is the point, the project re-started when I re-joined and no one else had continued working on it in the meantime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the often-misunderstood things about reputation is: It's not a zero-sum game. In a successful collaboration between two people, *both* can reap the benefits in terms of job offers, prestigious publications, funded grants, invitations to give talks.

In other words, focus on what the success of your PI/group leader could mean for you: It might mean that your position continues to be funded for a couple more years in which you can build up a better resume for permanent positions; it might mean that your PI's stature grows so that they can write you letters of recommendation that carry more weight; the success of your project might mean that they can stop working on other projects and work on things that you two are good at, and that that might mean more publications for you as well.

My take from your question is that you *envy* your PI's success. But that success is not to your detriment. It might be to your benefit, and that's what I would focus on.

Comment: As one mentor told me early in my grad student time, "Glory is not a thermodynamically conserved quantity"...

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, thank you for you thoughts about it. Indeed a very pragmatic answer. :)